# Data structure for imagelinks

Tags: iphone, datamodel

I'm developing a housing app with a number of houses which each have attributes. Those attributes are currently listed in a dictionary like: `House 0 {key: string, key: string}` etc.

I'm currently at the point where i want to add some images, which have to be downloaded and displayed. I already wrote the async image loader class. Im just wondering about how to structure the image links, and I would be the one to dive head first into something like this and spend two days debugging a crappy solution.

I thought about adding another dictionary named images in the current House 0 dict, and then looping through it. But I would love to hear better (easier) solutions.

Every house can have any number of images.

**Edit:**

I hope im not going to make anybody cry or murder me... But I did it like this:

`<key>Images</key>
     <string>image.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg</string>`

`NSArray *ar = [[dict objectForKey@"images"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`

**=D**

*Dont kill me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First refactor the dictionary to a class and add archiving if necessary.  In the long term a class will make the code simpler and less fragile.

If the images are really small saving them in a class may be OK but it is probably better to save them as files with the file names in the class.  If there is a possible image name conflict create a UUID of the image name.

Also consider Core Data if the data and images need to persist.

Comment: All data is located in a .plist which is downloaded off the web.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have all images in a single data store.

I would have an array of objects - each object would have (an image link) and an array of parents IDs - so an image can be used on multiple houses - (e.g. a floorplan not available image" or a real estate vendor logo image etc.).